# Find Related Messages in Outlook 2010 with New/Popup Window like in 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, vba

In Outlook 2007, to help clear the inbox, finding related messages would open a new small window that would allow to open the messages or to move them into folders easily, then go back and do the same with other emails on the inbox.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/tarpara/archive/2008/09/15/tip-of-the-day-outlook-2007-finding-related-messages-in-your-insanely-unorganized-inbox.aspx

However, in Outlook 2010, when looking for related messages through: Right-Click on the email -> Find Related -> Messages in this conversation

The emails list panel turns into a search panel where the results are listed, however when pressing back, the cursor loses track of the previously selected message in the list.

**Is there a way to have the same new/popup panel in Outlook 2010? Bonus if there's also a shortcut!**

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there doesn't seem to be a way to do this in the same way short of writing a macro. If you were to write a macro, you cannot assign a keyboard shortcut like you can in other Office applications, the nearest you can get to is to assign the macro to the Quick Access Toolbar. As long as it is in the first 9 items, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-*number* as a shortcut.

The nearest I could get without a macro was to add "Open in new Window" to the Quick Access Toolbar, then do the search in the new window. You can drag and drop from the alternative window into the original one so you can move around the folders using the original window while keeping the new window with the search.

Answer (score 0):

Disable "windows search":

1. Open `Control panel`
2. Turn windows features On/ffF
3. Windows search (Uncheck)
4. Restart

Now search on Outlook pops up a new window with search results.

Comment: There is no "Windows Search" entry for Windows Features in Win10.

Answer (score 0):

If Windows Search is disabled *for Outlook*, it will open Related Messages in the Advanced Find. This works in Outlook 2010, 2013, and 2016 (I haven't tried in 2019).

I usually do this by adding the `PreventIndexingOutlook` key in the registry.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Search]
"PreventIndexingOutlook"=dword:00000001
```

This doesn't seem to affect search speed if MSExchangeFastSearch is running with an Exchange account. The rest of Windows Search can remain on.

Comment: Does setting `PreventIndexingOutlook` to a value of 1 enable Advanced Find or disable it? It is unclear from your answer which outcome this achieves.

Comment: The setting enables advanced find and disabled unified/Windows find. It also enables the related messages popup.