# How to stop Outlook 2010 showing 'Find Related' in popup window?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

This is an odd behavior that has suddenly appeared on my Outlook 2010 (*on Windows 7*). I didn't set anything on it and now when I right-click a message and select `Find Related`,

[image: Find Related menu]

it shows me the results in a popup window instead of the reading pane (the reverse of what was asked [here](https://superuser.com/q/556842/61616)):

[image]

How do I set it back to the default behavior (showing the results in the reading pane)?

Answer (score 0):

**It is a bug**!!!!! Fixed by [KB3114560](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3114560):

> This update fixes an issue in which Outlook 2010 starts only in safe mode. This issue occurs after you install the December 8, 2015, update for Outlook 2010 (KB3114409).